# Mod_rewrite won't work Apache 2.4 / Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mod-rewrite, server, apache2, virtual-server

I'm setting up a Virtual Server by HostEurope:

Apache 2.4 
Ubuntu 14.04

I need the `mod_rewrite` function for my Wordpress Blog.

This is what I have done till now:

1. ssh connect to my server
2. `vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
3. changed: `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` (I tried `FileInfo` too)
4. `service apache2 reload`
5. `vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
6. added:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/html>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All 
           # I tried "FileInfo" too
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
    </Directory>`
   ```
7. `service apache2 reload`

Did i miss something here?

I called the `phpinfo()` function to check if `mod_rewrite` is listed there. But it's still missing.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Try `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apache/EnablingModRewrite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable mod\_rewrite for Apache 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Comment: Hey, tried this before, but it won't work. It says it's already enabled.

Comment: What is it that won't work? `mod_rewrite` doesn't have anything to do with PHP, which is why you won't see anything in `phpinfo()`.

Comment: It's worked for me. Thanks @KaiGuy